# linear combination of periodic sequence is also periodic?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $x_t$ and $y_t$ real periodic sequences such that the least common multiple of their periods exists. Then, given a constant $a$, $x_t+ay_t$ is also periodic with period, say,  $p$.

Does $x_t-ay_t$ also need to have period $p$?

Thanks in advance.

**Observations**

Let $p_1$ be the fundamental period of $y_t$. I see that $ay_t$ has the same period as $y_t$. Also, $-ay_t=a(y_t-2y_t)$ and $y_t-2y_t$ is also $p_1$-periodic. Hence $x_t-ay_t$ is a sum of $x_t$ with another $p_1$-periodic sequence.
I know that it is $p*$-periodic, with $p*$ being the least common multiple of both periods. But I'm interested on the fundamental period, and not its multiples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$x=\{(-1)^n\}=\{1,-1,1,-1,\cdots \}$$ and let $y=x$ and $a=1$.

Then $x+y=\{2,-2,\cdots\}$ has period $p=2$.  But $x-y=\{0,0,\cdots\}$ has period $1$.