# Linear combination of periodic sequence is also periodic? [2]

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

This question is related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3741614/linear-combination-of-periodic-sequence-is-also-periodic), where a simple counter-example was given to show a negative answer.

Let $x_t$ and $y_t$ real periodic sequences such that the least common multiple of their periods exists. Then, given a constant $a$, $x_t+ay_t$ is also periodic with period, say,  $p$.

Under which conditions $x_t-ay_t$ also has period $p$?

Thanks in advance.